Does jboss 7.4.4 and above patches work with JDK 17?
I am getting following error while running jboss with jdk 17.
 WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
14:28:15,062 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ManagementRealm",
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.remoting.remoting-http-upgrade-service.http-management is missing [org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ManagementRealm, jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management]",
        "org.wildfly.management.http.extensible is missing [org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ManagementRealm]"
    ]
}

I tried different jvm params but not working
I tried on jboss 7.4.7 and jboss 7.4.10`

JBoss EAP 7.4 supports JDK 17 only since JBoss EAP 7.4 Update 7. So you need to upgrade.
